# C++ socket programing endless loop

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make socket based program with server and client which correspond each other. It works if I'm using localhost ( 127.0.0.1 ), but if I try with my ip the server fail with endless loop. I'm not very familiar with socket programing so I was wondering if someone could help me with that problem.
Here is my server code:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
//SERVER
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


 // Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")


#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#include"drone.h"


int main()
{
WSADATA Winsockdata;
int iWsaStartup;
int iWsaCleanup;
SOCKET TCPServerSocket;
int isCloseSocket;

struct sockaddr_in TCPServerAdd;
struct sockaddr_in TCPClientAdd;
int iTCPClientAdd = sizeof(TCPClientAdd);

int iBind;

int iListen;

SOCKET sAcceptSocket;
int iSend;
char SenderBuffer[512] = "Hello from server";
int iSenderBuffer = strlen(SenderBuffer) + 1;
int iRecv;  
char RecvBuffer[512];
int iRecvBuffer = strlen(RecvBuffer) + 1;

iWsaStartup = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &Winsockdata);
if (iWsaStartup != 0)
{
    cout << "iWsaStartup Failed";
}

TCPServerAdd.sin_family = AF_INET;
TCPServerAdd.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
TCPServerAdd.sin_port = htons(8000);

TCPServerSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

iBind = bind(TCPServerSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&TCPServerAdd,     sizeof(TCPServerAdd));

iListen = listen(TCPServerSocket, 2);

sAcceptSocket = accept(TCPServerSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&TCPClientAdd,  &iTCPClientAdd);

iSend = send(sAcceptSocket, SenderBuffer, iSenderBuffer, 0);


while (1)
{
    iRecv = recv(sAcceptSocket, RecvBuffer, iRecvBuffer, 0);
    cout << iRecv << endl;
    cout << RecvBuffer << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

and here is my cliend code:

```
// Client
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")


#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512


int main()
{

WSADATA Winsockdata;
int iWsaStartup;
int iWsaCleanup;
SOCKET TCPClientSocket;
int isCloseSocket;

struct sockaddr_in TCPServerAdd;

int iconnect;

int iSend;
char SenderBuffer[512];


int iRecv;
char RecvBuffer[512];
int iRecvBuffer = strlen(RecvBuffer) + 1;

int iResult;

iWsaStartup = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &Winsockdata);
if (iWsaStartup != 0)
{
    cout << "iWsaStartup Failed";
}

TCPClientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

TCPServerAdd.sin_family = AF_INET;
TCPServerAdd.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("91.139.148.178");
TCPServerAdd.sin_port = htons(7000);


iconnect = connect(TCPClientSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&TCPServerAdd,  sizeof(TCPServerAdd));

while (1)
{
    cin.getline(SenderBuffer, sizeof SenderBuffer);

    int iSenderBuffer = strlen(SenderBuffer) + 1;
    iResult = send(TCPClientSocket, SenderBuffer, sizeof(SenderBuffer)+1,  0);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This loop won't be endless if you add some sort of condition to exit the loop instead of `1`.

Comment: What do you mean by "your IP"? If you're under a NAT, using your outer IP address will not work as the router will not forward it to you.

Comment: You have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) before your program starts really. Local variables, including arrays, are *uninitialized* and their values will be *indeterminate* (and seem random). Now think about that in the context of `RecvBuffer` and how you use it.

Comment: As for your *infinite loop*, well `while (1) { ... }` ***is*** an infinite loop.

Comment: You call a *lot* of function which can *fail*, but you do almost no error checking. Continue with that after fixing your UB.

Answer (score 1):

The loop is endless because 1 is always evaluating to true, therefore repeating the loop. Turn it into:

```
iRecv=0;
int failCount =0;

while (iRecv==0 && ++failCount <= 10)
{
    iRecv = recv(sAcceptSocket, RecvBuffer, iRecvBuffer, 0);
    cout << iRecv << endl;
    cout << RecvBuffer << endl;
    if(iRecv == SOCKET_ERROR ){
        //handle error
        iRecv=0; //if you want to retry
    }
}
```

Or shorthand

```
while (!iRecv)
```

At the first successful reception, iRecv will contain a value bigger than 0 and exit the loop.

I have also added a fail counter so that the program will quit after 10 attempts with no success.

Also remember to initialize all your variables to zero or default values.

Comment: the program works correct if I use ip address 127.0.0.1 and it fail if I use the ip address which i find when I type in google "what is my ip address". I want to find why is that and how to fix it.

Comment: Your firewall and UAC probably prevent this from working.

Comment: Well that is a networking problem... first thing is open a shell and type ping followed by your ip and see if it works... but this is going to be off topic for this question. example: `ping 63.66.344.21`

Comment: Ok next check if the port you are using, 8000, is open. UAC or other firewall policies might mess up with the port

Comment: I change the port and the console fails again with endless loop with the same message "
ММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММяяяяММММММММ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
-1"

Comment: ***is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file*** That looks like an error that your program executable was not found in the current folder (or your windows PATH). Weird since you got the MMM... message. Or did you type MMMM

Comment: I think this means your program exited. And whatever you typed is the next command of your command line which `cmd.exe` states is not a program it can find..

Comment: The console on the server side faild that way immediately when i run it before I can even type something on the client console

Comment: If you are on Vista and above you may need an elevated prompt / UAC elevation (the first time) to allow the server to listen on your external network address. The only reason I say may is your security settings may be set to a lesser level. At work I write a client server application and on every Install I have to accept the UAC prompt for the listening to work. This happens on all machines except an old Windows 7 laptop.